# Use SoapUI to transfer byte[] is Possible?

Tags: web-services, soap, byte, soapui, soap-client

I'm trying to pass a byte [] through the SoapUI program. Is it possible to do this? Or should I modify the soap and pass the data in another way for me to work?

If it is possible, how can I do it ?, and in case it is not possible in which you recommend me to match the byte []

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Question is unclear.

Comment: I'm trying whith soapui program (https://www.soapui.org/) to send one array of byte (byte[]) if I don't write nothing start accion in this  and I can debug it, but if I copy one binary file, return me one error where it tells me that the format of variable is wrong.

Comment: The comment too did not help. Can you explain with a screen shot? there isn't anything called `soapui program`. You may probably using some different terms which aren't standard, hence could not get what it is.